# How can i get value of an element from TinyMCE text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE text editor . Everything is fine But i just want to get html of an element from editor . suppose my content in editor is

```
<h1 id="title">06/27/2015Meeting Notes</h1>
<h2>Date</h2>
<p>06/11/2015</p>
<h2>Attendees</h2>
```

I want to get the value of `h1` tag having `title` id . How it is possible ?
I have tried this one

```
var name=tinymce.get('#title').getContent();
```

this is returning the selection

```
alert(tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent());
```

didn't work for me . 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/ this is text editror

Comment: @MilindAnantwar.. **[this is tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php)**.. Its an editor plugin.. :)